# GenyMotion and Cisco conflict; when working simultaneously

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, genymotion, cisco

---

`GenyMotion` stops working when I connect `Cisco AnyConnect`; after which, `GenyMotion` needs restart and it will never run again, while `Cisco AnyConnect` is connected!

What could be the problem?

*# I hope notes below would be helpful:*

-`Cisco AnyConnect` is connected via a US server.

-`GenyMotion` works perfect when `Cisco AnyConnect` is not connected.

-I've tried various VDs; but the same trouble is experienced!

---

Answer (score 1):

You should make changes to your `GenyMotion` ip and DNS to be suitable for those of the `Cisco` . . .
It may work

Comment: thanks! @alireza daryani, also mentioned a similar approach, I'll get back with results.